# Incorporating tide times into AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

What would be the best way to incorporate changing tide times into an AnyLogic model? I would like to use the times to effectively block and unblock a port. I have looked at the schedule option and the format (Start: Day1, Time) doesn't seem the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can model the tide by a reoccuring timed trigger.
AnyLogic offers the **Dynamic Event** for this, an event that can reschedule itself.

Depending on how you have the time data for the tides (list of DateTimes, fixed periods, database), you can retrieve that value for each new rescheduling of the dynamic event.

I attached a screenshot of a simple sample model. Here I assume you have got a list with the interval in minutes between each port-affecting tide moment (Low Tide/Port Blocked - High Tide/Port Open  - Low Tide/Port Blocked - and so on....) . The dynamic event then sets a boolean variable portBlocked, but depending on your needs you could also trigger a Statechart Transition, block flowchart modules, or trigger a function.

[image: Tide Trigger Example Model (Screenshot)]

The Action code of the Dynamic Event:

```
portBlocked=!portBlocked;
create_MyDynamicEvent(tideIntervalsInMinutes.get(tideCounter),MINUTE);
tideCounter++;
```

Explanation of the code:

1. Trigger your needed actions (here simple boolean variable)
2. Reschedule the event for the next tide change
3. Update the tide counter (used to retrieve the corresponding tide interval time from the list)

In the startup code of the model you will have to trigger the Dynamic Event once initially, for this just use the same code as point 2 above.